# Make javascript function and prototype definition in same declaration?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is it possible to combine this whole definition into one declaration instead of breaking it apart?

First Part

```
var Pan = function(){};
```

Second Part

```
Pan.prototype = {

 //private variables
 Id: null,

 //public methods
 GetId: function(){
    alert(Id);
 }
}
```

Comment: good question! i'm trying it all sorts of ways because you've got me interested now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do:

```
var Pan = function () {
    var Id = null;

    this.GetId = function(){
        alert(Id);
    }
};
```

Comment: Very nice, this will accomplish the goal of the question which was to combine the definition into one definition.

Comment: Except that this is not the same as what you have in your question. Every instance of `Pan` will have its own copy of the `GetId` method, rather than sharing the one on the prototype.

Comment: @JamesAllardice - So this will use more memory?

Comment: @TravisJ - Yes. Every time you instantiate `Pan` a new copy of the method has to be created. If it was declared on the prototype (of which there is only one), every instance shares that copy (first, the instance is checked for a property of that name, which isn't found, so the prototype is checked instead).

Comment: @JamesAllardice - So the point here is to just use a prototype I suppose. This technically does answer the question, although it may not be the best idea if there will be a large collection of `Pan`s.

Comment: @TravisJ - Yeah, I would just use your original code. This does kind-of answer the question, but the code behaves differently to what you had originally which I didn't think was the point of your question, but I'm not 100% clear on what you are actually trying to do, especially reading the comments on the other (now deleted) answer! It's also worth noting (as was noted in the deleted answer) that your "private variables" are not private at all: `Pan.prototype.Id` will access that from anywhere `Pan` is in scope.

Comment: As for the private comment, I realize it is still public. But there is enough facade there to make it private-esq enough for this implementation. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11281/discussion-between-travis-j-and-james-allardice)

Comment: Downvoted because this is absolutely different from the original code.